# general n-dimensional name of Pixel and Voxel

Tags: image-processing

In 2D images we call the smallest picture elements pixels, in 3D images we call them Voxels (for volume pixels).

**I was wondering if there is a word that can denote them both (pixel and voxel)**, and possibly be used to mean any n-dimensional picture element.

For example, I want to write something like:

> Given an n-dimensional image with N pixels/voxels

Where I want to replace ***pixels/voxels*** with just one word that would also denote these elements in other dimensions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16071467/125507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypervoxel):

> hypervoxel (plural hypervoxels)
>
> 1. A multidimensional analogue of a voxel

From [Digital Design Media - Mitchell & McCullough, 1995](https://books.google.com/books?id=JrZoGgQEhKkC&pg=PA271):

[image: Pixel X,Y Voxel X,Y,Z Hypervoxel X,Y,Z,T 12.1 A hypervoxel in a four-dimensional coordinate system]